# Could anyone check my work for a set proof question from discrete math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Question: For all sets A, B, C, (A-B)-C is a subset of A-(B-C).

My proof:

Assume x is an element of (A-B)-C, then x is an element of A and x is not an element B and C.

if x is not an element B and C, then A-(B-C) = A and we know that x is an element A.

Therefore: For all sets A, B, C, (A-B)-C is a subset of A-(B-C).

Comment: "if x is not an element B and C, then A-(B-C) = A" .... um, what?  Let A = (0,3), B= (1,4), C = (2,5).  Let x = 1/2 $\in$ A-(B-C) so... because 1/2 $\not \in B$ and 1\2 $\not \in C$ we can conclude that A = (0,3) = A-(B-C) = (01]U[2,3)$?  How do you figure that?  "and we know that x is an element of A".  Um, we know that because we said so...

Comment: If $x \in $ (A-B)-C then $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$.  If $x \not \in B \subset B-C$ then $x \not \in B-C$.  So $x \in A - (B-C)$.  So $(A-B)-C \subset A - (B-C)$.  Or more directly.  $X \subset X-Y$ so $(A-B) - C \subset A-B$.  If $Y \subset Z$ then $X - Z \subset X-Y$ (If $x \in X$ but not in Z then $x \in X$ but not in Y).  So $A-B \subset A-(B-C)$.  So $(A-B)-C \subset A-(B-C)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would clarify your proof as follows:

Assume x is an element of (A-B)-C, then x is an element of A and x is not an element of B. If x is not an element of B, then x is not an element of (B-C).
If x is an element of A and x is not an element of (B-C), then x is an element of A-(B-C).

So every element of (A-B)-C is also an element of A-(B-C), making the former a subset of the latter.